# Create .js Break Point in script within HTML file in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to create a breakpoint in a  within a .html file with Visual Studio?

I get the option to create a breakpoint within a .js file but not within an .html file (even within the  tag.

```html
<html>


<body>
    <p> testing</p>
    <script type='javascript'>
    alert('testing');
    alert ('testing2');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your case is so rare that this probably isn't supported. I'd suggest move your code to a separate file.

Comment: @marzelin  - are you saying that it's rare to have js inside an html page?

Comment: it's rare to debug js inside of an html file because they are (and should be for perf reasons) small & simple scripts. What do you need inline scripts for?

Comment: @marzelin  I want to *start* the debugging in the html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to File -> Preferences -> Settings -> Debug ->debug.allowBreakpointsEverywhere = true